# How to make x-csrf token from referrer and client agent and send it in api header in NEXT JS

Tags: php, reactjs, api, next.js, fetch-api

**I'm trying to make fetch data from api(php server) in my NextJs app
the api requires x-csrf and x-referrer to authenticate** the client
if x-csrf matches the csrf generated on backend it validates the request and sends back data

The csrf is generated by the php backend is by taking refrer and user agent of the request
and converting it into md5 string with some confidential string
then it comapares this csrf with the one that is sent in rquest headers and if both matches it serves the data

Same logic should apply to the client to generate the csrf and should be sent into request headers

**I have tried generating this csrf in my nextjs web site
by accessing referrer and user agent from context and document object
and sending in rquest headers in both getServerSideProps requests and
client side requests** but it wasn't getting validated by api server

I need help in

1. **How can I make csrf and make it globally accessible**
2. **How to access referer and user agent in such a way that it can also be sent to

   getServerSideProps requests also.**

please let me know any approach that would satisfy these conditions

Thanks